# Why I can't bind a ObservableCollection<T> in Windows phone 7.8 and below?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

**Context:**
Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone (Update 2)
Project build based on the official template Panorama (Windows Phone OS 7.1)

**Problem:**
All codes works OK in WP8, but when in WP7.8 and WP7.1, it seems that I can't get the ViewModel get binded to the view. And when I look into it. I found the problem.

**Codes:**
In my view's code-behind, I bind the view model to the view using the code below:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new pageViewModel();
}
```

I found that when in WP7.8 and below, the property which binds to a ListBox is abnormal, its value is

> Could not evaluate expression

but in WP8, it's ok.

this property's related code is below in ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> tmpClass = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
tmpClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MyClass>>(callbackjsonstring);
this.propertyA = tmpClass;
```

## **How to solve it?**

**A little more digging:**

I put a breakpoint at the initialization of tmpClass. I found 2 different results in WP7 and WP8, I think this is the problem:

**in WP8:**
after running the code, type "tmpClass" in Immediate Window, it shows:

> Count = 0;

**in WP7:**

after running the code, type "tmpClass" in Immediate Window, it shows:

> {System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection}
>       base {System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection}: {System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection}
>       _busy: false
>       CollectionChanged: null
>       PropertyChanged: null

Comment: The result from `tmpClass` doesn't tell you much, other than that there is a different debug visualizer / ToString() on those two runtimes. That doesn't mean the object is any less "initialized". Basically, I think everything after "I put a breakpoint..." is likely to be a false positive and unrelated to the problem

Comment: @MarcGravell  I found that when I do "this.DataContext = new viewmodel();" in the code-behind. One of its property's value is "Could not evaluate expression", and it should be this ObservableCollection<T>, so I debug into it - -

Comment: WP7 only support binding to properties (I don't know if it has changed with WP8). Are you sure `propertyA` is a property with a getter, and not just a field?

Comment: @AlbertGao When the Windows Phone debugger shows "Could not evaluate expression", it usually means the value is null

Comment: @KooKiz the PropertyA has a get and set, you know, kinds of MVVM boilerplate code. I thought it maybe a bug of JSON.net, so I comment the Json.net part , and DIY a object and transfer to the propertyA, the result is the same...WP8 ok, WP7.5 not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to bind a listbox to the observable collection? if so, do it like so:

```
Listname.ItemsSource = tmpClass.Collection;
```

This should actually work, at least thats the way I do the Databinding

Comment: Thanks,But have done it in the xaml, and bind the whole datacontext to the view in the code-behind